# Adding Docker logs stored in another machine to ELK

Tags: docker

I am trying to send logs of docker containers on a machine to ELK stack that's active on another docker machine. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker apps logging with Filebeat and Logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33432983/docker-apps-logging-with-filebeat-and-logstash)

Comment: ...but use the remote host's name/IP address instead of `localhost` or 127.0.0.1, in either format in the first two answers to that question.